# Flutter Provider with Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I have a provider with 3 state Response (Success, Error, Running) and consumer which listening to this provider. Is it possible to push to another route, when response from provider is Success? Here is my consumer:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _splashWidget(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _splashWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AccessTokenProvider>(builder: (context, myModel, child) {
      switch (myModel.accessToken.status) {
        case Status.COMPLETED:
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainRoute);
        return null;

        case Status.ERROR:
        return ErrorScreen();

        default:
          return SplashProcessing();
      }
    }, );
  }
}
```

Is it a good case to make navigation in this way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Widget _splashWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AccessTokenProvider>(builder: (context, myModel, child) {
      switch (myModel.accessToken.status) {
        case Status.COMPLETED:
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => 
           Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainRoute)); // can also use: Future.microtask(() => Navigator.of(context). pushReplacementNamed... );
        return Container(); // always return a widget in the build method, not null

        case Status.ERROR:
        return ErrorScreen();

        default:
          return SplashProcessing();
      }
    }, );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your widget should not return null (Status.COMPLETED). So if you want to use the navigator AND show widgets depending the state of your consumer, you should add a **listener** who will push to the MainRoute, and a builder (like your consumer here) to show the ErrorScreen or SplashProcessing.

Comment: Could you provide any examples or links on how to add listener on provider? Sorry, I'm new in flutter. Thanks!

Comment: Sure ! Take a look at this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc, the BlocConsumer would be a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But is it possible to achieve that goal without using of bloc?

Comment: Okey, try that: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainRoute)); This method will execute its content after the build method is done. I think you still gonna have to return something like an empty container.

Comment: Hah. Yes, I already read about this solution, I quess you could move this comment to answer, I'll mark it as accepted later. But still I'm waiting for better clue)))